nilReason cannot be populated while parsing xml with jaxb if nil=true
I have an application developed with Quarkus framework with Java 17. I am parsing xml messages like this with jaxb library
<xm:temperature uom="N/A" nilReason="http://codes.wmo.int/common/nil/notObservable" xsi:nil="false"/>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
 </dependency>`


if xsi:nil="false"
All fields including nilReason is populated but if xsi:nil="true", there is nothing, field value is just nullyour text
Is there any way to populate nilReason when xsi:nil="true" as well?
I have tried same thing on empty simple demo project other than Quarkus, but same
